# Angular 4 - Reactive forms get result from array

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to Angular 4 and trying to display information in input fields based on what is selected inside a select option field.

```
<select
   formControlName="selectCar"
   class="form-field">
   <option value="">Pick a car</option>
   <option *ngFor="let car of carOptions" [value]="car.value">{{car.name}}</option>
</select>
```

The above select is being populated successfully and I can pick a car from the dropdown. The data is coming from the array below:

```
readonly carOptions = [
    {
        value: 'HYUNDAI_I20_BLUE',
        name: 'Hyundai i20 blue',
        price: 250,
        currency: 'EUR'
    },
    {
        value: 'HYUNDAI_I20_RED',
        name: 'Hyundai i20 red',
        price: 275,
        currency: 'EUR'
    }
];
```

But what I want to do is populate two input fields below with the price and currency of the car that was just selected, how do I go about doing this? So the final code could be:

```
<select
   formControlName="selectCar"
   class="form-field">
   <option value="">Pick a car</option>
   <option *ngFor="let car of carOptions" [value]="car.value">{{car.name}}</option>
</select>
price: <input type="text" value="250">
currency: <input type="text" value="EUR">
```

Help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you already have code that handles the option selection?

If so, in that routine you can use `setValue` or `patchValue` to update the data on the form. This is an example I tailored to your fields from my app:

In the ngOnInit method:

```
this.myForm.get('selectCar')
            .valueChanges
            .subscribe(value => this.updateControls(value));
```

Another method in the component:

```
updateControls(value) {
    this.myForm.get('price').setValue(value.price);
    this.myForm.get('currency').setValue(value.currency);
}
```

NOTE: This requires that you add the two input elements to the form as well:

```
price: <input type="text" value="250" formControlName="price">
currency: <input type="text" value="EUR" formControlName="currency">
```

Comment: Great example.  Since it's a subscription, wouldn't it also be good to unsubscribe?

Comment: My understanding is that the form is destroyed when the component is destroyed, so unsubscribing was not necessary. But I have not found documentation to back that up.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the change events emitted by the select and set the values of your inputs.

```
<select
   (change)="onChange($event.target.value)"
   class="form-field">
   <option value="">Pick a car</option>
   <option *ngFor="let car of carOptions"
   [value]="car.value">{{car.name}}</option>
</select>

price: <input type="text" [value]="price">
currency: <input type="text" [value]="currency">
```

Then set the values, when the select is changed:

```
onChange(selectedCar) {
    const car = this.carOptions.find(c => c.value === selectedCar);
    this.price = car.price + '';
    this.currency = car.currency;
}
```

See this [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/Cva2TUW9abMFzeHRWsjj/)

Answer (score -1):

1) Bind selected value

```
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
   formControlName="selectCar"
   class="form-field">
```

2) Display the selected value

```
price: <input type="text" value="250" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue.price">
currency: <input type="text" value="EUR" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue.currency">
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was thinking sbout ngModel but isnt it double when you are using reactive forms?

Comment: `ngModel` should not be used with reactive forms.

Comment: Sorry didnt notice the header